NextJS 14 ( App Router ) authentication middleware
I am struggling to create a simple jwt cookie authentication middleware where what I want is if there is no cookie to redirect to login and if there is to redirect to dashboard route
here is my current middleware.ts file
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import Routes from './constants/Routes';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const token = cookies().get('token')?.value;
  const isLoginRoute = request.nextUrl.pathname === Routes.LOGIN;

  if (!token && !isLoginRoute) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(Routes.LOGIN, request.url));
  } else if (isLoginRoute && token) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(Routes.CALCULATE, request.url));
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [`${Routes.DASHBOARD}/:path*`, Routes.LOGIN],
};

But I am always getting too many redirects and the website is crashing. What should I do ?
I tried to remove the redirect it works but how will I redirect to login if no token
I am expecting the redirection to work without the website crashing

Can i see your LOGIN, DASHBOARD, and CALCULATE CONSTANT ?

const Routes = {   LOGIN: '/login',   CALCULATE: '/dashboard/calculate',   DASHBOARD: '/dashboard',   PAST_DATA: '/dashboard/past-data',   CLAUSES: '/dashboard/clauses', };
@cantdocpp

Can you try to not use else if, just try to use regular if

same thing is happing @cantdocpp
